# SEO Compare two pages on the same site

Tags: seo

Hi I have 2 pages on my site both targeting the same keywords, one of them is performing significantly better than the other. Is there some automated tool that can help me analyse the factors and see why there is this ranking difference?

Till now I've found these tools:
http://www.seomastering.com/site-comparison.php
http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [on-page seo checker](http://www.seoworkers.com/tools/analyzer.html).  It will give you a complete rundown of the SEO factors for each page.

Then take a look at your external and internal links pointing to both pages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a tool to analyse which is better. I would first check to see the following differences between the two pages:

- Content length
- Amount of usage of targeted keywords/phrases and semantic words
- Images/video
- Links to the pages (including site interlinking)